# Findbug - ANT xslt stylesheet source code references

Tags: ant, findbugs

I have an ANT target that runs findbugs twice on the same source code to generate a xml and html report

```
<delete dir="${findbugs.dir}"/>
<mkdir dir="${findbugs.dir}"/>        
<findbugs 
    home="${findbugs.home}"
    output="xml"
    outputFile="${findbugs.dir}/findbugs.xml"
    jvmargs="${findbugs.jvmargs}"
    timeout="${findbugs.timeout}"
    effort="${findbugs.effort}">
   <sourcePath path="${src.dir}"/>
   <class location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
</findbugs>

<findbugs 
    home="${findbugs.home}"
    output="html"
    outputFile="${findbugs.dir}/findbugs.html"
    jvmargs="${findbugs.jvmargs}"
    timeout="${findbugs.timeout}"
    effort="${findbugs.effort}">
   <sourcePath path="${src.dir}"/>
   <class location="${build.classes.dir}"/>
</findbugs>
```

This is dumb since the html report can be generated from the xml report using

```
<xslt in="${findbugs.dir}/findbugs.xml" out="${findbugs.dir}/findbugs.html" style="${findbugs.home}/default.xsl"/>
```

but the generated html report doesn't have the correct source code references. Any ideas on how I can get this working and avoid the duplicate findbugs call?

Updated after answer

```
with output="xml"

<BugInstance type="REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION" priority="2" abbrev="REC" category="STYLE">
   <Class classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties">
      <SourceLine classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" start="20" end="788" sourcefile="AggregationProperties.java" sourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java"/>
   </Class>
   <Method classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" name="setAggregateProperties" signature="()V" isStatic="true">
      <SourceLine classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" start="86" end="148" startBytecode="0" endBytecode="489" sourcefile="AggregationProperties.java" sourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java"/>
   </Method>
   <SourceLine classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" start="140" end="140" startBytecode="308" endBytecode="308" sourcefile="AggregationProperties.java" sourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java"/>
</BugInstance>

with 'xml:withMessages'

<BugInstance type="REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION" priority="2" abbrev="REC" category="STYLE" instanceHash="b7a7c8f292d2a8432680a1c971fb93b3" instanceOccurrenceNum="0" instanceOccurrenceMax="0">
   <ShortMessage>Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown</ShortMessage>
   <LongMessage>Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown in com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties.setAggregateProperties()</LongMessage>
   <Class classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" primary="true">
      <SourceLine classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" start="20" end="788" sourcefile="AggregationProperties.java" sourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java" relSourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java">
         <Message>At AggregationProperties.java:[lines 20-788]</Message>
      </SourceLine>
      <Message>In class com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties</Message>
   </Class>
   <Method classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" name="setAggregateProperties" signature="()V" isStatic="true" primary="true">
      <SourceLine classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" start="86" end="148" startBytecode="0" endBytecode="489" sourcefile="AggregationProperties.java" sourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java" relSourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java"/>
      <Message>In method com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties.setAggregateProperties()</Message>
   </Method>
   <SourceLine classname="com.x.y.aggregate.AggregationProperties" primary="true" start="140" end="140" startBytecode="308" endBytecode="308" sourcefile="AggregationProperties.java" sourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java" relSourcepath="com/x/y/aggregate/AggregationProperties.java">
      <Message>At AggregationProperties.java:[line 140]</Message>
   </SourceLine>
</BugInstance>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`output="xml:withMessages"`

From the [documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html),

> If set to "xml" (the default), output is in XML format. If set to "xml:withMessages", output is in XML format augmented with human-readable messages. *(You should use this format if you plan to generate a report using an XSL stylesheet.)*