# FindBugs- HTML Report generation from Findbugs XML report

Tags: findbugs

I am using FindBugs (version 1.3.9) Eclipse Plugin. I run findbugs and saved findings in XML file. 
I need to generate HTML Report of the XML report.

Do we have any tool existing?

I want the output to be similar to:
http://mevenide.codehaus.org/maven-eclipse-plugin-plugin/findbugs-report.html

Answer (score 3):

I am using something like this as command line:

```
$ ./findbugs -textui -userPrefs edu.umd.cs.findbugs.core.prefs  -progress\
    -maxHeap 1500 -nested:false -output results/outputfile.html -effort:max\
    -low -sortByClass **-html:fancy.xsl** -auxclasspath servlet-api.jar\
    -auxclasspath selenium-server-standalone-2.43.0.jar\
    -auxclasspath commons-lang-2.6.jar ~/Downloads/bodgeit-master
```

The options can be used to generate HTML output.

You can also use a simple utility called unionBugs to collect all bugs found in different sub-projects, which take arguments output file name with "-output" switch followed by any number of xml files. 
Steps:
1. Go to **bin** subdirectory in **Findbugs** directory
2. Run `./unionBugs -output <output_file_name.xml> inputfile1 inputfile2 ... inputfilen`
3. Later, run a command **convertXmlToText** to transform XML into HTML file.

```
./convertXmlToText -longBugCodes -html <input_file1.xml> <output_file.html>
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate HTML report directly via FindBugs, you may use the following (likely undocumented) command line:

```
java -cp findbugs.jar edu.umd.cs.findbugs.PrintingBugReporter -html analysisResult.xml >output.html
```

In general it's just an XSL transformation. The supported XSL files are bundled in findbugs.jar as resources.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with the FindBugs Eclipse plugin, but I know that the FindBugs Ant task has an option to have the `output` get produced in `html` format.  Is there some way to configure the FindBugs Eclipse plugin to produce html output?

[FindBugs Ant Task Manual](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use xslt to generate the report from the findbugs.xml.

This post shows how to do that:
[Findbug - ANT xslt stylesheet source code references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3944129/findbug-ant-xslt-stylesheet-source-code-references)